# JavaScript, / jQuery determining if the URL contains a Min String

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's what I want to happen

Anything the variable hash contains: #/projects/X

X being anything other than blank, I want to fire an alert

Fires Alerts

```
#/projects/X
#/projects/X/boo/123/123/ads/asd/ads/ads
```

Does not fire an alert

```
#/projects/
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (/^#\/projects\/.+/.test(window.location.hash)) {
    alert("Some project");
}
```

Comment: I want to know when it's #/projects/XXXXX meaning X is anything. So should it really be != 0? What is indexOf supposed to do here?

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the #/projects/ part, and see if there's anything left. If so, do something:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;

if (hash.indexOf('#/projects')!=-1) {
  if (hash.replace('#/projects/','').length > 0) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually wait that doesn't work... because for other HASHS like #/contacts/ it would return true which is bad. It should only work for #/projects/ does that make sense?